# Pandas - groupby one column and then sort by all remaining columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to group the dataframe bellow by 'player_slug' and *then* sort all columns for each (numeric) 'mean' column.

Please note that column values are already mean values.

This is `df.head(5)`:

```
   player_slug  player_id player_nickname  player_team player_position  ...   DD_mean   DP_mean    status  price_diff  last_points
0   paulo-andre      37604     Paulo André          293             zag  ...  0.000000  0.000000  Provável        0.11          1.7
1       evandro      37614         Evandro          277             mei  ...  0.000000  0.000000    Dúvida       -1.78          2.8
2         betao      37646           Betão          314             zag  ...  0.000000  0.000000  Provável       -0.14          0.1
3  rafael-moura      37655    Rafael Moura          290             ata  ...  0.000000  0.000000  Provável        2.89         22.2
4         fabio      37656           Fábio          283             gol  ...  1.257143  0.057143  Provável        0.42          2.0
```

---

I have tried to create a function and pass all features, like so:

```
 columns = ['score_mean','score_no_cleansheets_mean','diff_home_away_s',
            'n_games','score_mean_home','score_mean_away','shots_x_mean','fouls_mean','RB_mean',
            'PE_mean','A_mean','I_mean','FS_mean','FF_mean','G_mean','DD_mean','DP_mean',
            'price_diff','last_points']

def sorted_medias(df, feature=None):
    df_agg = df.groupby(['player_slug', 'player_team']).agg({feature:'sum'}).sort_values(feature, ascending=False)
    print (df_agg)
```

and finally:

```
for feature in columns:
   sorted_medias(df_medias, feature)
```

But I'm unsure of using 'sum', or 'mean', in agg, since values are already means.

What is the way to go here?

Comment: I dont get your question...maybe I'm not being clear

Comment: I just want to group by player and then sort the values that are already there, ending up with each sorted rows in a unique dataframe.

Comment: example: group by player, then sort players by goals. groupby player again, but then sort players by a different column. and so on.

Comment: why do I need `mean()` if I already have mean values?

Comment: If you already have mean values then pick one (I assume each group that have multiple rows of same player will have mean goals repeating correct?) `df.groupby(['player_slug'])['goals'].min().sort_values(ascending=False)` I did `min` you can also do `max` since all values are the same

Comment: thank you. this gives the same result from my question....

Comment: I posted this as the answer. Pleas accept if this helped. Also please remove some of your comments above to make the comment section cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is what the OP was asking for. Grouping by player and pick any value inside the group as the values are already aggregated.

`df.groupby(['player_slug'])['goals'].min().sort_values(ascending=False)`